# VBA script in Outlook 2010 rule

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, vba

I use Outlook 2010.

I am using a script that takes a e-mail to a certain address and converts it to a ticket through our ticket system. I created the script through the Developer tab in Outlook.

I tried making a rule that uses this script on all incoming mail, but when i go to select the script in the rule creation I have none in my list.

Does anyone know where I need to save the VBA script for it to show up in my list of choices?

Answer (score 3):

niton is correct. For more details on this (because I just read the Microsoft Support article), check out [KB Article 306108](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306108). Basically, if you want to use a script in a Rule, the script must accept one argument because the Rules Wizard will pass it one argument. Also, the argument must by of type **MailItem** or **MeetingItem**, just like niton has above. If you have anything else in your script, it will not be available to the Rules Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Save in any module. The first line should look like

Sub RunAScriptRule(MyMail As MailItem)